# How to get specific data from Firebase using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was trying to get some data organized under a specific Id from a realtime database

For example, this is my JSON object :

```
{
    1: {
        Name :"karan",
        Bio:"hello this is Karan",
    }
    2: {
        Name :"gandhi",
        Bio:"hello this is gandhi", 
    }
}
```

I want all the data to be arranged in `1`. Is there any way to do this? It would be better if the data would be arranged in a object in the following format :

```
var data = {
    Name : "karan",
    Bio : "hello this is Karan",
}
```

This should be in the same order given in the original object

Thank you

Comment: How do you want the data arranged; I'm assuming in an array. Also, please add any attempts you've made

Comment: I want the data arranged in a object

Comment: Can you please give me a example in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `Object.values()`.

Let's suppose your database looks like:

```
{
    1: {
        "Name" : "karan",
        "Bio" : "hello this is Karan",
    },
    2: {
        "Name" : "gandhi",
        "Bio" : "hello this is gandhi", 
    }
}
```

You want to retrieve data without the keys "1" and "2". Your query will be:

```
// Let's call your node "foo"
firebase.database().ref("foo").once("value").then(data => {
     console.log(Object.values(data.val()));
});
```

Try to execute the following:

```js
var data = {
    1: {
        "Name" : "karan",
        "Bio" : "hello this is Karan",
    },
    2: {
        "Name" : "gandhi",
        "Bio" : "hello this is gandhi", 
    }
}

console.log(Object.values(data));
```

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/values

Comment: Do I have to specify the reference to key `1` ? Or the normal reference to the whole object is fine?

Comment: Depends on what you want. My example is for the whole object. If you want only a specific key you have to change for `Object.values(data.val()["1"])`